# jQuery "hover state" - Test if element is no longer being hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I know you can test, if a element is being hovered over by using:

```
$('.foo:hover').length > 0;
```

or on my case:

```
$(this).filter(':hover').length > 0;
```

Either will return a value of true if the element triggers the `'mouseenter'` event. How ever i wish to test if an element is no longer being hovered over. I tried using:

```
!($(this).filter(':hover').length > 0;)
```

as well as

```
$(this).filter(':hover').length < 0;
```

But it is not giving me the desired result.

[Example using above code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWRPbO)

The context for this is a drop down menu i am working on.

Comment: Use mouseleave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not listen for the following:

```
  $('.box').on('mouseleave', function() {
    console.log($(this).filter(':hover').length > 0);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have already mentioned `mouseleave`; here's a snippet that's very similar to Robert's answer:

```
$('.box').on('mouseenter', function() {
  console.log($(this).filter(':hover').length > 0);
  $(this).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).off('mouseleave');
    console.log('bye!');
  })
});
```

The difference is that it concerns itself solely with the original element in question, and kills itself once it fires.

Comment: Thank you, you answer is also valid but may i ask why kill then event ?

Comment: Oh, no specific reason. Just thought I'd throw it out there for variety.